# pandas groupby, transform and join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe and I would like to groupby and join the strings of a column together. So something like the below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
    'txt': ['sth', 'sth else', 'sth', 'one more thing', 'sth else', 'sth else'],
    'status': ['open', 'open', 'closed', 'open', 'open', 'open']})

df.assign(output=
    df.where(df.status=='open')
      .groupby(df.id)
      .txt.transform(lambda col: ', '.join(col.fillna(''))))
```

which gives me this

```
   id   txt             status  output
0   1   sth             open    sth, sth else
1   1   sth else        open    sth, sth else
2   2   sth             closed  , one more thing
3   2   one more thing  open    , one more thing
4   3   sth else        open    sth else, sth else
5   3   sth else        open    sth else, sth else
```

is there a way to

1. not have duplicate values (like in row 4 and 5)
2. not have a leading comma if a status is 'closed' (like in row 2 and 3)
   so that I would get

```
   id   txt             status  output
0   1   sth             open    sth, sth else
1   1   sth else        open    sth, sth else
2   2   sth             closed  one more thing
3   2   one more thing  open    one more thing
4   3   sth else        open    sth else
5   3   sth else        open    sth else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and combine with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.assign(output=
    df.where(df['status'].eq('open'))
      .groupby(df['id'])['txt']
      .transform(lambda col: ', '.join(col.dropna().drop_duplicates()))
         )
```

Output:

```
   id             txt  status          output
0   1             sth    open   sth, sth else
1   1        sth else    open   sth, sth else
2   2             sth  closed  one more thing
3   2  one more thing    open  one more thing
4   3        sth else    open        sth else
5   3        sth else    open        sth else
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes it does, OP only wants the strings that originate from rows with the "open" condition. Looks for instance at group 2, this would give `sth, one more thing` instead of `one more thing` ;)

Comment: You could not transform everything within the `groupby.transform` since `transform` only considers **one** column. You could process everything with a `groupby.apply` and then `map` the result, but that's probably less efficient.